# List top n items in column, which have highest sum in second column

Tags: excel

So I have a spreadsheat like this, each row is a contract with a company:

```
Company | Revenue
------- | -------
Facebook| 1000000
Google  | 1000000
Facebook| 100000
John Doe| 123
John Doe| 100
John Doe| 8
John Doe| 50
foo inc.| 100
```

Now I want to list the top n companies with the most revenue. Lets say n=2 it should look like this:

```
Company  | Revenue SUM
-------- | -----------
Facebook | 1100000
Google   | 1000000
remainder| 381
```

I'm looking for an Excel formula that does this, I cannot use VBA. I tried array formulas with `SUMIF` and `MATCH`, but I don't seem to get it right.

Comment: This would be a great chance for you to try using pivot tables.  Just highlight your table, click the pivot icon, and off you go.

Comment: If n is variable I wouldn't suggest trying to output with excel formulas. Try pivot tables or VBA, probably in that order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this purely with formulas *(no pivot table or VBA)*.  With data in column **A** and **B**, in **E2** enter:

```
=LARGE(B:B,ROW()-1)
```

and copy down.  This sorts the contents of column **B**.  Now we need to find the rows in which the values reside.  In **F2** enter:

```
=MATCH(E2,B:B,0)
```

and in **F3** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$1:$E3,E3)>1,MATCH(E3,INDIRECT("$B" & F2+1 & ":B9999" ),0)+F2,MATCH(E3,B:B,0))
```

and copy down.  This formula gets the rows and handles the duplicates in column **B**.

Finally in **D2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,F2)
```

and copy down:

[image]